# Send CEC command from TV to Android phone

Tags: android, hdmi

I’m trying to send HDMI-CEC command from a TV set to my Android phone (both of them can support CEC protocol). Although I have already read the CEC specifications, the problem is that I don’t know how to send CEC command ONLY via the HDMI cable. I know libCEC has done much thing; it seems that it requires purchasing their Pulse-Eight USB - CEC Adapter.
Does everyone know the rough progress of CEC command transmission ONLY via HDMI cable?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

CEC goes over HDMI pin 13, and only over HDMI.
The Pulse-Eight USB adapter can be used when your HDMI doesn't support CEC.
For example Video cards do not have this function build in.

Besides normal TV's, Sounds systems and Blueray players.
Device like RaspberryPi and Odroid (but not all models have the software) support it.
Software: XBMC or OpenELEC
For a full list is just search the web/forums.

But to get a command from you TV to your phone depends if your phone hardware supports CEC and your Android kernel has CEC enabled.
Android with CEC is not yet by default done.